# Input shape of dense layer in keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

I'm trying to build a new model

```
batchnorm_model = Sequential()
batchnorm_model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(28,28,5), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')) 
batchnorm_model.add(BatchNormalization())
batchnorm_model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')) 
batchnorm_model.add(BatchNormalization())
batchnorm_model.add(Dense(2))
# Compile your model with sgd
batchnorm_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And my input data set has below information

```
print(X_train.shape)
(7000, 28, 28, 5)
```

But I got an error message:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 890, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 139, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 243, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1787, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5119, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 28, 28, 2) are incompatible
```

How to identify the input shape of the first dense layer? I know it has to be number of pixels in image, but I try to identify as (28*28*5,), still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Working with images could be sometimes difficult as they could have different channels, formats and sizes.

I don't see the full code, but the best practice is to thoroughly check the different input sizes and the data types using:

```
print(np.shape(image))
print(type(image))
```

And reshaping it with a function that could be something like this:

```
image = np.reshape(image, (28, 28, 2))
```

Note: I used to spend hours blocked because of this kind of issue. The best solution I know is prototyping the problem with just the necessary elements to aim every dependency. You could save a lot of time.